# I have an If statement that isn't behaving like I expect it too, maybe I'm stacking it wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an if/then statement that is not behaving as such. My level of expertise is about 1/10.

- I'm trying to take a user input value and give a variable output
  depending on the value.
- My script gives me 10, which is each function returning 5, which is wrong

```
 def abs_func():
    plank_input = raw_input("How long can you hold a plank?:")
    situps_input = raw_input("How many situps can you do?:")

#checking the input we just recieved
    print "Plank Input:",plank_input
    print "Situps Input:",situps_input

#This Checks the plank time against my values.
    def abs_char1(plank):
        global abs_rate1
        if plank >= 120:
            abs_rate1 =+ 5
        else:
            if plank >= 90:
                abs_rate1 =+ 4
            else:
                if plank >= 60:
                    abs_rate1 =+ 3
                else:
                    abs_rate1 =+ 2
        print "Abs 1:",abs_rate1
        return abs_rate1

#This Checks the plank time against my values.
    def abs_char2(situps):
        global abs_rate2

        if situps >= 120:
            abs_rate2 =+ 5
        else:
            if situps >= 100:
                abs_rate2 =+ 4
            else:
                if situps >= 80:
                    abs_rate2 =+ 3
                else:
                    abs_rate2 =+ 2
        print "Abs 2:", abs_rate2
        return abs_rate2

    a1 = abs_char1(plank_input)
    a2 = abs_char2(situps_input)

    print "a1:",a1,"a2:",a2
    abs_rate = a1 + a2
    print abs_rate


abs_func()
```

I want it to spit out the correct values, like 3 and 4, totaling 7.

But, it always prints out 5 and 5, totaling 10 and I don't know why...

Comment: if you figured it out, you may as well delete your question...

Comment: _"'raw_input()' and 'input()' apparently handle things differently. "_ - Well in Python 2 they are. In Python 3, `raw_input` was renamed `input` and the old `input` function was removed.

Comment: instead of nested if/else, why not use `elif`?
 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if

Comment: It's probably going to be closed, but in the future, please format the question to that readers can efficiently understand what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not using Python 3, cause `raw_input` is just renamed `input()` in Python 3. When I tried running your code with `input()`, it had a bunch of problems because you are comparing a string value (`input()` returns a string) to an integer value (120 for example).

Try fixing this for the time being and keep us posted with your new results. :)

Answer (score 0):

raw_input() and input() handle things differently, so when I used raw_input() instead of input() It changed the code enough to fail me out. 
Why it did that I do not know, but it did.